# C++ Converting a text file list with numbers and words into an integer 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, int

I have a basic text file which has one entry per line, most entries are are numerical, however there are a few lines with the word  and  (evenly spaced) in them. Here is an example of one such spacing between  and :

```
<event>
4
0
0.1005960E+03
0.2722592E+03
0.7546771E-02
0.1099994E+00
21
-1
0
0
501
502
0.00000000000E+00
0.00000000000E+00
0.17700026409E+03
0.17700026409E+03
0.00000000000E+00
0.
-1.
21
-1
0
0
502
503
0.00000000000E+00
0.00000000000E+00
-0.45779372796E+03
0.45779372796E+03
0.00000000000E+00
0.
1.
6
1
1
2
501
0
-0.13244216743E+03
-0.16326397666E+03
-0.47746002227E+02
0.27641406353E+03
0.17300000000E+03
0.
-1.
-6
1
1
2
0
503
0.13244216743E+03
0.16326397666E+03
-0.23304746164E+03
0.35837992852E+03
0.17300000000E+03
0.
1.
</event>
```

What I need to do is create a numerical matrix (using only the numerical values) where each column holds all the data values between each separate instance of  and .

This is what I have so far:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <string> data; 
    string str;

  ifstream fin("final_small.txt"); 
  while (fin >> str) 
  {                  
    data.push_back(str);
  }
  fin.close(); // Close the file.

int N = data.size();

  int matrix[13][19];

  for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 19; j++) { 

  matrix[i][j] = data[i];

}  
}
}
```

Obviously this is a huge work in progress.  First of all, I read the text file in to a vector, which can not be of type int because of the words. This then causes problems later on when I try to input it into the matrix.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, one could give the hint to create a string for each line, and then a stream from each string. Each stream will be read to fill one row in the matrix. If the attempt to read a number from that stream (with the usual >>) fails, one must have read an "and" which can be ignored, iiuc. The stream must then be reset, the rest of the "and" must be read away , and reading ints continued till eof.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, use std::stoi to convert a string to an int. Note that std::stoi will throw an exception of type std::invalid_argument if the conversion cannot be performed.

Answer (score 1):

Could you give some example inputs? What you could do is iterate through each line and only convert characters that are numbers. You can check this with the `stdlib` function `isdigit()` which you can see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/). You can then use `atoi()` for numerical conversion. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks guys! I updated to topic with an example of my input file.  I'm looking into what you both referenced

Comment: After looking at the example input you provided, my method seems like it doesn't need to be changed much. Again, iterate through every row and make sure all entries are alphanumeric (you can use `isalnum()` in stdlib.h for this). If the row is alphanumeric, then convert it to a float using stdlib's `atof` method (documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/)).